# How to get list of existing entities(tables) in core data

Tags: ios, core-data

How to get list of existing entities (tables) for a particular schema (Managed Object Model) in core data. I just started implementing core data concept and stuck with these points.

Something like:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbName';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should read through [Apple's Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). To get the entities for a particular `NSManagedObjectModel`, you would use one of the following (this assumes you have an `NSManagedObjectModel` named `objectModel`):

```objectivec
NSArray *myEntities = [objectModel entities];
// Array of all entities in the model
```

or

```objectivec
NSDictionary *myEntities = [objectModel entitiesByName];
// Dictionary of entities in the model, with the entity names as keys
```

You can read more in the [NSManagedObjectModel Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSManagedObjectModel).

It appears you're coming from a SQL background (as I was). There are a number of concepts in Core Data that are different - sometimes for the better, once you understand them, sometimes requiring more work than a simple SQL statement you may be used to. I think it's important to approach Core Data without SQL "baggage" and treat it as if you're learning how to use a database for the first time - this will help avoid frustration.

Comment: Thanks David, yes I have to keep SQL behind; looking for the prime differences now. If you can suggest some references(links) it will be helpful

Comment: I was initially introduced to Core Data, along with iOS development, through "iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" (http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_rd_edition_), which gave a good introduction. From there I mostly referenced the Apple guide linked in my answer and, of course, lots of searches here on Stack Overflow. There are books dedicated to Core Data, but I haven't picked one up yet. I think migration between model versions is where most people get tripped up and where Core Data itself tends to be most finicky, and even buggy.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift it would be:

```swift
let model: NSManagedObjectModel

let entities: [NSEntityDescription] = model.entities
// or
let entitiesByName: [String: NSEntityDescription] = model.entitiesByName
```

and to get a list of names

```swift
let enititesNames: [String] = entities.compactMap(\.name)
```