# Get all entities from Model.xcdatamodeld

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

In my project I am using `MagicalRecord` framework (implementation of active record pattern for `Core Data` on iOS). How can I retrieve all existing ENTITIES from my `.xcdatamodeld` file? I have to iterate though all entities (classes that inherit from managed object in my project) to truncate stored data.

I have only default configuration set in my model file. So for the following data model:

[image]

My code that show how it should look like:

```
NSArray *myEntities = // Retrive my entities.
foreach (Class *c in myEntities) {
    [c MR_truncateAll];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I have found the solution [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652745/how-to-get-list-of-existing-entitiestables-in-core-data). The answer is pretty simple:

```
NSArray *allEntities = [[NSManagedObjectModel MR_defaultManagedObjectModel] entities];
for (NSManagedObject *mo in allEntities) {
    [[mo class] MR_truncateAll];
}
```